# How to create dynamic editable react-table on onClick

Tags: reactjs, react-table

```
tableData: {
    Revenue_Variable_Cost_Tier_1: [
      { 1: 'Volume',2:'',3:'',4:'',5:'',6:'',7:'',8:'',9:'',10:'',11:'' },
      { 1: 'Unit Price($),2:'',3:'',4:'',5:'',6:'',7:'',8:'',9:'',10:'',11:''},
      { 1: 'Unit Cost($)',2:'',3:'',4:'',5:'',6:'',7:'',8:'',9:'',10:'',11:''}
    ],Revenue_Variable_Cost_Tier_2: [
      { 1: 'Volume',2:'',3:'',4:'',5:'',6:'',7:'',8:'',9:'',10:'',11:'' },
      { 1: 'Unit Price($),2:'',3:'',4:'',5:'',6:'',7:'',8:'',9:'',10:'',11:''},
      { 1: 'Unit Cost($)',2:'',3:'',4:'',5:'',6:'',7:'',8:'',9:'',10:'',11:''}
    ]
```

}https://react-table.js.org/#/story/editable-table

by using above link created an editable table for Revenue_Variable_Cost_Tier_1, now I wanna add one more dynamic table in oneshot using onClick function(Eg:Revenue_Variable_Cost_Tier_2)

Comment: or else need a function to create n dynamic tables using n arrays in above tableData

Comment: is there any clone option in react-tables?